# Show image with path from an API in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i get data from an API and i want to display the picture via a path that the api give to me

I have this simple code to get a random actor,
And i have all of his information save as a json such as this data  :
profile_path: "/j2Yahha9C0zN5DRaTDzYA7WtdOT.jpg"

How can i use this path to show the picture with`<img src="??"/>`

````
function Game() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const API_KEY_MOVIE_DB = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  useEffect(() => {
    const myInit = {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
      };
      const random_0_20 = parseInt(Math.random() * (200 - 1) + 1);
      const actor = fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/${random_0_20}?api_key=${API_KEY_MOVIE_DB}`, myInit)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        setApiResponse(JSON.stringify(response));
        setIsLoading(false);
        localStorage.setItem(`${random_0_20}`, JSON.stringify(response))
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, [page]);

  return (
    <div>
        {isLoading && <p>Loading</p>}
        {apiResponse}
        <img src={apiResponse.profile_path}></img>
    </div>
  );
} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the state to a *string*:

```
setApiResponse(JSON.stringify(response))
```

And a string has no property called `profile_path`:

```
<img src={apiResponse.profile_path}></img>
```

If the result from the API is an object, just set the state to that object:

```
setApiResponse(response)
```

You should also initialize the state to an object, rather than an array:

```
const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState({});
```

Possibly even with the property set to a default value, to avoid "undefined" rendering in the markup:

```
const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState({ profile_path: '' });
```

Strings, objects, and arrays are all very different things.  Keep the types of your variables consistent so the behavior of the code remains consistent.

Comment: I just add all of you're saying, thank's for that ! 
but so now that the path is well store and i can see the path string in console.log(apiResponse.profile_path)
Even now, the image is still blank with the path ` <img src={apiResponse.profile_path}/>`

Comment: @QuentinRiols: What is the runtime value of `apiResponse.profile_path` when this happens?  When you right-click on the element in your browser and inspect it, what is the exact `<img/>` element in the DOM?  Are there any errors at all in the browser's development console or network tab of the debugging tools when it tries to fetch the image?

Comment: In the element in the browser it's look like <img src="/rfJtncHewKVnHjqpIZvjn24ESeC.jpg"/>
I don't understand where should I find the rest of the <img src={}/>path

Comment: @QuentinRiols: And is `"/rfJtncHewKVnHjqpIZvjn24ESeC.jpg"` the expected value?  If so then the code is working as designed.  But if you don't actually have an image at that path then that's a separate problem entirely.  Perhaps the API from which you get this data expects you to use that path on *their* server, instead of on *yours*?  So you're prepend it with a URL to their service?

Comment: @QuentinRiols: It's worth a try.  If that doesn't work then you may need to check with that 3rd party API to find out more information.